# Can I call this dc to ac

Tags: ac, dc, dc-ac

[image]
I thought about making the current pass through the resistor the the ground 
And after switching the direction the ground change to the opposite direction

Comment: You can call this a confusing schematic.

Comment: If the 555 were synchronized to the AC line, it would still be a mess. Relays are much too slow to sync at 50/60 HZ

Comment: Relays can do 50Hz, badly.  try an relay with a series diode on AC some time.  I wouldn't want to switch much more than a small fraction of the rated power at that switching rate.  ifthe relay is rated for a million operations that's like half a day before it's due to fail.

Comment: @Jasen just theoretical till now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can call that DC to AC.

You have designed an electromechanical chopper which supplies square-wave AC to the load.

But there's a few problems,

if one of the relay gets stuck you'll short circuit the supply

you'd probably get better efficiency. and greater reliability with a transistor H-Bridge instead of the relay bridge,

also the 555 is not set-up for equal on and off periods so the AC won't be balanced, there'll be a DC compnent that leaks through.

the inductors cause the relay contacts to arc when opening which will accelerate wear, some sort of snubber would help (a parallel diode on each inductor would probably suffice)

the relay coils need snubbers (eg diodes parallel with their coils)

running two relays may exceed the 100mA max output source current typcial of the NE555

I don't know where you're going get relays fast enough, that 555 is running at what? 200Hz?

Answer (score 2):

What you have there in the upper part of your schematic is a mechanical commutator made of relays. 100 years ago this was a common way to create AC from batteries. Instead of a NE555, they used a relaxation oscillator controlled by a neon lamp. Short-time uses only because of the contact wear.

Comment: yeah, used in car radios called a "vibrator" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vibrator_(electronic)

Comment: Now @AbdullahNofal can brag to all his friends about his homemade vibrator! :P